# Not able to get the header.php in my wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So, the problem is that I do not know what arguments should I send, neither I do think it would be necessary considering (which could change if know what to do).

I'm using creating a wordpress theme using php, so on. So I create a three files: index.php, footer.php, header.php.

```
<?php get_headers()?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Header</p>
        <p>main</p>
        <p>footer</p>
        <p>final</p>
    </div>
```

the thing is that wordpress throw me this error on the customize page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeISG.png)

Comment: You're attempting to use PHP's [get_headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) which requires a parameter, instead of WordPress's [get_header](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/), which does not.

Comment: So, what should I use?

Comment: I didn't include it in the code section but also use the <?php get_footer()?>, and I didn't had any problem rendering that part.

Comment: As I said, WordPress has `get_header()`. Notice the difference in the `s`

Comment: Thank you!!! it's really helped me a lot! I didn't notice the s at end lmao.

Comment: If your question was simply a typo, feel free to remove it.

Comment: should I? it's looks like a simple question, but I don't think I have been the only beginner facing that problem because of commiting a simple mistake.

Comment: But this is the first time asking something here, neither do I know the asking policy, so I will appreaciate if you explain why I should do it

Comment: No worries Erick.  If you think that your question will help others, I'll let other people decide to close it.  I voted to close, as "caused by typo" is a reason that we can vote to close questions. In my opinion, this isn't a helpful question, and simply googling `wordpress get_headers` - the first result shows `get_header()` so I think your issue could have easily been resolved by reviewing the wordpress function library, or simply using google to see if maybe you did something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, well I did! xd. But as I said, I didn't get what argument should be sent in  get_headers and once I read the article I was like "what the heck are those attributes?", neither did I read deeply the WordPress website enough to come across that answer. Anyways,  thanks, man! I appreciate your comment. I'm going to look for that library, so this thing doesn't happen twice.